# I'm having trouble loading a webpage neatly in webview

Tags: android, browser, load, webview, size

Everytime I load a page in the webview, the webview tries to squash the web page into a small frame. However, in the standard android browser, it loads the page at the full size and allows the user to zoom in however much they decide.

Is there anyway to make a webview load a page like the default web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
WebView wv;
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();

webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //when you define webview settings just add this to enable zoom
wv.setInitialScale(1); //lets set initial zoom to 1% to see whole page when it loads
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. Thank you.